# Why does neo4j fetch recursilvely?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have a node called PracticeArea that could have a parent practicearea and children practiceareas.

When I pull a particular practice area, I expect it to bring me that specific node with its parent and its children. But, neo is also giving me children of its parent, parent and children of all its children, in short loading the whole graph.

I get the same result whether I use Spring Data neo4j repository, custom query or neo4jTemplate.

```
interface PracticeAreaGenericRepository extends GraphRepository<PracticeArea> {

@Query("MATCH (n:PracticeArea {practice_area_id:{0}})-[HAS_CHILDREN_PRACTICE_AREA*1]->(c) MATCH (n)-[HAS_PARENT_PRACTICE_AREA*1]->(p) RETURN n, p")
PracticeAreaData findByPracticeArea(String uuid);
}
```

PracticeAreaData.java

```
@QueryResult
public class PracticeAreaData {

@ResultColumn("n")
PracticeArea node;

@ResultColumn("p")
PracticeArea parent;

/* Getters & Setters */


}
```

Please suggest whats going wrong..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your query is missing one critical piece, the `WITH` to join the two together and pass the `n` from the first part to the second part. Without that you are just finding all of the nodes that have parent practice areas and all of the parent practice areas.

```
MATCH (n:PracticeArea {practice_area_id:{0}})-[HAS_CHILDREN_PRACTICE_AREA*..1]->(c)
WITH n
LIMIT 1
MATCH n-[HAS_PARENT_PRACTICE_AREA*..1]->(p)
RETURN n, p
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense but I am getting the following error: java.util.NoSuchElementException: More than one element in org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IterableWrapper$MyIteratorWrapper@d706480. First element is 'com.xxx.practicearea.dto.PracticeAreaData@50a1a18f' and the second element is 'com.xxx.practicearea.dto.PracticeAreaData@58ca300'

Comment: because it returns a collection of practice areas you would have to add "LIMIT 1" to always limit it to 1 element

Comment: also this `-[HAS_CHILDREN_PRACTICE_AREA*1]->` means paths of length 1 or more !!

Comment: For simplicity, I have taken out children out of the query.     @Query("MATCH (n:PracticeArea {practice_area_id:{0}})-[HAS_PARENT_PRACTICE_AREA*1]->(p) RETURN n, p LIMIT 1 ")
but I am still getting children of parent under parent node. So its going up and traversing back down again.

Comment: sorry - gave a poor answer and then disappeared for a few days.  I made some changes to the query per Michael's comments.